# RoR - undefined method `merge'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, textfield

I'm studing Ruby on Rails with the "RoR Bible" by Thimothy Fisher. But one of the examples doesn't work. It's code - http://pastebin.com/gtjLsdt0
The error is: `NoMethodError` in `Contact#new` where line #4 raised:

```
undefined method `merge' for "first_name":String
```

that's my contact_controller. I'm just retyping example's code, and there weren't any words about merge

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @contacts = Contact.find(:all);
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new;
  end

  def create
  end

  def update
  end

end
```

What is wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lol that example is completely wrong!

Instead of writing sth like this:

```
<%= f.text_field 'contact', 'first_name' %>
```

You should write

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>
```

Because by using `f.field_type` you assign the field to the `:contact` form which provides the `f` methods by iteration! Also you can write

```
<%= f.label :first_name, "description of first_name" %>
```

Instead of writing it manual!

// I loked up the book you refered it seems to be quit outdated. You may buy "The Rails 3 Way" or sth. that can hold up to the current rails version!